Como puedo mandar a producción un proyecto Laravel de manera local?
Resulta que tengo un proyecto ya casi por terminar y tengo que mandarlo a producción a un servidor local o maquina local para compartirlo en la red de ellos sin la necesidad de estar escribiendo el comando "PHP artisan serve", e estado buscando pero solo encuentro de como hacerlo a un host en linea yo lo que quiero es hacerlo a manera local, en la empresa se usa xampp y según e buscado se configura el xampp para que haga el resto pero de igual manera no e logrado hacerlo funcionar no se si alguien tiene como hacerlo.
pdt: es en windows y en composer probé con el comando composer install --no-dev pero aun así tengo que ejecutar el comando "PHP artisan serve".

Estaba revisando y creo que este video tiene lo que necesitas saber. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USPg8TCaEHo
